# JPEG Error #61 occuring randomly on the same image in Delphi

Tags: delphi, jpeg, delphi-7, internet-component-suite

I load the same JPEG image while testing my program. Sometime it loads fine, sometime it doesn't. The file doesn't change a bit during the process. I download it from localhost using Overbyte ICS THttpCli component.
How is it possible the same code sometime work and sometime doesn't?

I use Delphi 7.

Comment: Sounds implausible. Save away to a file on the local machine, and see if you can reproduce the error with that local file. You may need to do this a few times. Probably the comms are broken somehow. I bet you the files actually do differ and that the corrupt file really is corrupt.

Comment: Is it possible that sometimes your HTTP request fails (returns something other than 200 OK), or that you're sometimes reading an incomplete file? Log the file size and see if it's different for a successful read or a failure.

Comment: It could be useful to dump each downloaded image into file and compare those files by some tool like legendary Dave Mitchell's Cable

Comment: @craig65535 I am handling HTTP errors. Every request gives me code 200 and exactly same size file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it was a case. Somehow the files downloaded from my localhost have same size always but different hashes sometimes. Weird thing. Seems I have to investigate my Apache and Overbyte ICS ThttpCli component. Thanks!

Comment: @pf1957 I compared hashes, they are different indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Apache server works fine- same file requested 100 times was identical every time. However THTTPCli returns corrupted files- almost every time. Same file is returned with different bytes changed in every case. And I am not doing anything special- like downloading huge files, resuming downloads, decoding gzipped files etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with THTTPCli component from Overbyte ICS (Internet Component Suite) V8. Error happens in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE 3.
My problem was because I had put:

```
Application.Processmessages;
```

in HttpCli.OnDocData-assigned procedure.
After removing it the component works fine. The application doesn't seem to freeze even without it.

Comment: Not the case here. I have an extremely simple brand new application in Delphi 10 Seattle. Loading a JPEG image worked fine in a `TImage` at first, but once I changed this control to enable `Stretch`, `Proportional`, and `Center`, not I get this error. Oddly, the exact same thing happens when using the Graphics32 `TImage32`.

Comment: To make things weirder, I was trying two different JPEG files, it happened every time. Then I opened another file, and it worked. Now the other 2 files which failed before work fine. And I made ZERO changes, not to the code or the files.